# MySQL concurrent updates of a single row

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, concurrency

What is the common pattern in RDBMS for storing frequently-updated data.
Suppose I have a table, which stores queue id and last client id.

```
CREATE TABLE queues(
   queue_id int primary key,
   last_client_id int
);
```

And I have a number of client connections, which try to get `last_client_id` and increment it. I want to have guarantee, that each client connection will get unique `last_client_id` for the same `queue_id` and there will be no misses in these retrieved values.

However, as MySQL uses locking, supported TPS is limited. Currently I see problems starting from 60 transactions per second trying to update the same row. Transactions wait for locks and are later failed with `lock wait timeout`.

1. Can this problem be solved with re-designing RDBMS table? What are the options?
2. Is there any generic way to optimize it in MySQL?
3. If you solved a similar problem, please, share your thoughts.

Comment: why you don't use a autoincrement field.?

Comment: how would this help? You have one row for one queue. `client_id` should be unique within one queue

Comment: autoincrement would guarantee that it would be unique. I'f that is not feasible, make last_client_id unique itself, so at least you get only unique ids. if it has only need to be unique use instead of ids uuids,

Comment: it means this table always has only 1 record?

Comment: I think he's saying the table has one record _per queue_. So there are multiple rows, and the last_client_id needs to be a sort of auto-increment for each queue. MyISAM can do this, but InnoDB can't.

Comment: How many queues are there?  Please show us the tentative SQL statements that you are applying.